# Is there a way to chain session data in Session Windows on Apache Beam?

Tags: apache-beam

I have the following user data readed from a PubSub topic:

```
{'user_id': 'A', 'event_time': '2022-08-30 09:00:01'}
{'user_id': 'A', 'event_time': '2022-08-30 09:00:30'}
{'user_id': 'A', 'event_time': '2022-08-30 09:01:10'}
```

And I need to group the input data by 'user_id' key, chaining event_time's to generate start_time and end_time session data. Example:

```
{'user_id': 'A', 'start_time': '2022-08-30 09:00:01', 'end_time': '2022-08-30 09:00:30'}
{'user_id': 'A', 'start_time': '2022-08-30 09:00:30', 'end_time': '2022-08-30 09:01:10'}
```

I have tried with session windows, but this only concatenates by pairs, resulting:

```
{'user_id': 'A', 'start_time': '2022-08-30 09:00:01', 'end_time': '2022-08-30 09:00:30'}
{'user_id': 'A', 'start_time': '2022-08-30 09:01:10', 'end_time': Null}
```

This is the code that I am developing:

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
events = (
p
| "Read from Pub/Sub" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=topic_name)
| "Add Timestamps" >> beam.Map(lambda x: beam.window.TimestampedValue(x, to_unix_time(x["event_time"])))
| "Key for user_id" >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x["user_id"], x))
| "Apply Session Window" >> beam.WindowInto(window.Sessions(int(window_size)), timestamp_combiner=window.TimestampCombiner.OUTPUT_AT_EOW)
| "Group by key" >> beam.GroupByKey()
)
```

Any help will be gratefully received.

Thanks!

Comment: Can we assume that the input data is already in order (i.e., the time is monotonically increasing)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to have the next session start when the previous session ends?

You could do this by following your sessionized output with a [stateful DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/). (Make sure to re-window into GlobalWindows first, as state is bound per-window.) Note that there is no guarantee that the data arrive in order, but you can set a timer to ensure you've received all data up to a point, and emit any fully-specified sessions up to that point.

See also the relevant section of the [programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#state-and-timers).